# ASP MVC, Lazy Loading, and JSON Serialization. How to fill other properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, serialization

Ok, so I feel like this is way more trouble than it should be.

I'm making a REST api for a mobile app using C# ASP mvc.  I am using ASP MVC 4 and EntityFramework 6.

Since LazyLoading does not agree with JSON serialization, I disabled it in the EDMX xml.

```
    <EntityContainer Name="Entities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="false">
```

So now when I make my request, only the immediate properties are loaded - looks fine.

I was looking for a method to load the associated properties - (in a way that they will only have their initial properties and not cause a circular reference), and found this nice little website by Microsoft.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

I followed the instructions for "Explicit Loading" (LazyLoading still turned off).

```
    public JsonResult GetUser(int id)
    {

        var user = entities.UserProfiles.Find(id);
        entities.Entry(user).Collection(x => x.ArtistsFollowing).Load();


        return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Circular Reference.  Why Microsoft would allow you to disable lazy loading and explicitly load different properties....which lazy load - Beyond me.

So then I made Views to load the associated properties - but linq nor lambda wouldn't let me me put them into a list of the appropriate property type (which is generated by EF but so what?).

[image: Trying to get List of Artists a User Follows]

So I ask, what is the best way to load an Entity and its associated properties without creating circular references when serializing?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `Artist` an existing class?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing quite a bit actually.

First off. `Json` was never really designed. For anything. So it has a pretty glaring issue, that it can't handle circular references AT ALL. There have been some attempts to patch this, but as a standard, there is no solution.

Secondly, you want to use `.DbSet<T>.Include(user => user.Following)` to load your associations.

Thirdly, if you are using WebApi, it should use Newtonsoft's Json Serializer, which does support a form of custom Json with circular support, google how to turn that on.

Fourthly, EF allows you to disable lazy loading, because of the N+1 problem. Many developers rather see their code not work, so they know what to fix, than to have lazy loading kinda work and slow their app down.

Its not your fault, EF and WebApi has a lot of fun nuances for you to learn.

Comment: First off, EF handles association (nested classes) just fine.

Comment: @TonyX Nested classes are NOT associations. They are POCOs that are declared within the body of another class.

Comment: I get you, but your answer seemed to imply (admittedly, maybe only to me as I read it) that based on the question, you used the terms interchangeably, because I don't see anything specifically regarding the use of nested classes, and this appears to be an issue with entity associations and JSON serialization. Not down voting you or anything, as there is some good info in the answer, just a matter of clarification.